# Cannot Import Lottery from Brownie even after successfull Compilation

Tags: contract-deployment, contract-debugging, chainlink, brownie

I am trying to deploy the Lottery Contract but it doesn't seem to work since Brownie throws an error, `ImportError: cannot import name 'Lottery' from 'brownie'` . I have already compiled the Contract without any errors. It happen's when I am trying to deploy it.

**What I have already done:**

- Removing **Lottery.sol** and recreating one wtih the same source code.
- Deleting `/builld` folder and re-compiling via `brownie compile` command.
- Rechecking the Global Compiler Version, Python Interpreter etc.

**Here is the source code for the contract:**

- [Lottery.sol](https://pastebin.com/mEgyXcp9)
- [Deploy.py](https://pastebin.com/xhDRX0Dj)

Comment: Could you include your brownie config file? I'll try to re-create the error as close to your setup as possible

Comment: @TheRef The error was in the constructor of Lottery.sol . It wasnt public. I think I forgot to add it. Below answer resolved it. Thank you for response Ref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your constructor should be `public` to be usable from brownie console.

As far as I know `internal` constructor are only usefull for `abstract` contract.

Comment: It resolved the issue. Contract is now successfully deploying both on local and Rinkeby Chain. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you already got the answer.

Even I had the same problem working with brownie and python but without a constructor in my solidity code. The solution to that is, making sure that the contract name whose build data will be generated must be the same as the file name. Or it be won't be recognised.